# Could not get current location using Google Map API (GMSMapView)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I try to get the direction from current location to other point using Google Map API. Everything is OK when i input the origin point and destination point manually. But, when i try to set the origin point as current location, the location is null as the following code:

```
mainMap=[[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:[mainMap.myLocation coordinate] zoom:13];
mainMap.camera=camera;
mainMap.myLocationEnabled=YES; // <---- The blue point appear on map: it's exactly my location

[self.view addSubview:mainMap];

//Get mylocation
CLLocation *myLocation = mainMap.myLocation; // <----- NULL
```

Is there any body know what is my problem here? Tks a lot

Comment: mainMap.myLocation is only set asynchronously because it isn't designed to block (which would be bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is: Getting a location is asynchronous and how you do it is expect it to block till its there... which is not how it works

you have to add a KVO observer inn the map and observer myLocation.
Then when your observe method gets called, you get the myLocation.

(that's how the blue dot works too :))

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //...
    [self.mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:"myLocation" options:0 context:nil];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [_mapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
        CLLocation *l = [object myLocation];
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks! I'm trying your suggestion

Comment: I still cannot get my current location, using ios 8.3

see this please 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016422/ios-getting-my-location-regularly-and-setting-button-to-get-my-location-google