# Google Maps iOS SDK: How to start map on user's location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to set the *initial* center location of a GMSMapView. There's about 2000 tutorials out there that show you how to set it with arbitrary coordinates like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera2];
```

But I don't want to start in Australia and than move to wherever the user actually is. I want to just start wherever the user is, just like the way the Google Maps app works.

Here's what I think I know:

- If I set `mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;` I should be able to retrieve the device position with `mapView_.myLocation`
- BUT the GPS data is probably not available yet during `viewDidLoad`, so that value will be 0,0 initially or nil or whatever (something not useful).
- Device location can be managed with a `CLLocationManager` to track if the device moves, etc.

But how do I pass the data that's (eventually) stored in the `CLLocationManager` to the GMSMapView so that I start in the right place?

This seems like it should not be so difficult, but after 2 hours of searching, I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with so far...

This SO question is similar to mine: [Could not get current location using Google Map API (GMSMapView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607358/could-not-get-current-location-using-google-map-api-gmsmapview/20611812#20611812)

And [this blog post](http://cobbservations.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/centering-gmsmapview-on-users-current-location-google-maps-sdk-for-ios/) modifies the answer in the above post, with some really helpful explanation.

It seems to work, but there's still a bit of a glitchy flicker when it loads, and I think it's because of the way I'm setting the camera position initially. If anyone knows a better way to do this, please tell me!