# ios getting my location regularly and setting button to get my location - Google Map not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I am working on Google Map Module , using 1.9.0 Bundle, to find my location on regular basis , say 10 seconds and create a button to get my location button as one of mapview settings

When it comes to the execution and location service is turned on, there are no responses after clicking the right bottom button or not, the location manager is not working. I can show any signs of using location service.

I am not sure what I am missing on setting this map as i follows strictly on the SDKDemos - ios google demo project to set my module. Would you please tell me the exact way to set it ?

The following is my code:

```
@implementation MapViewController


-(bool)isNetworkAvailable
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef address;
    address = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, "www.apple.com" );
    Boolean success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(address, &flags);
    CFRelease(address);

    bool canReach = success
    && !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired)
    && (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable);

    return canReach;
}


- (void)requestAlwaysAuthorization
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSString *title;
        title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([self isNetworkAvailable]){
        NSLog(@"connected ");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"not connected ");
    }

    CarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float latitide = [defaults floatForKey:@"lati"];
    float longitude = [defaults floatForKey:@"longi"];
    NSString *desp = [defaults objectForKey:@"desp"];


    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"assadsd arrived map");
    if(latitide!=0.00&&longitude!=0.00) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitide, longitude);

        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitide  longitude:longitude  zoom:12];
    }else{
        camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.2855200   longitude:114.1576900  zoom:12];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900);
    }


    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    marker.snippet = @"HK";

    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    mapView_.delegate = self;

    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    });


    if(desp.length > 0 ){
        marker.title = desp;
    }

    // Setup location services
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Please enable location services");
        return;
    }

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Please authorize location services");
        return;
    }


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;


           [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];



          [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];



    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 5.0f;


    [mapView_ addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                      options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                               NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                      context:NULL];


    marker.map = mapView_;



    self.view = mapView_;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    GMSCircle *geoFenceCircle = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900) radius:1400];
    geoFenceCircle.tappable = true;
    [geoFenceCircle setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5]];

    geoFenceCircle.strokeWidth = 13;
    geoFenceCircle.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    geoFenceCircle.map = mapView_; // Add it to the map.


    NSLog(@"assadsd configured d map");

}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if (!firstLocationUpdate_) {
        // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
        // location.
        firstLocationUpdate_ = YES;
        CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        mapView_.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                         zoom:14];
    }
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [mapView_ removeObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                     context:NULL];
}




-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didDragMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    [mapView clear];

    // Re-draw marker
    marker.map = mapView;

    // Create your circle with the new marker
    GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:marker.position radius:1000];
    circ.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    circ.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circ.strokeWidth = 5;
    circ.map = mapView;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%ld",(long)buttonIndex);

    if (alertView.tag == 121 && buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //code for opening settings app in iOS 8
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%@",error.userInfo);
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"Please authorize location services");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"CLLocationManager error: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
    return;

}

-(void) handleDoubleTap {
    NSLog(@"location double tap ");
}
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}



// CLLocationDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    if (markera == nil) {
        markera = [[GMSMarker alloc] init] ;
        markera.position   = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.86, 111.20);
        markera.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.97f); // Taking into account walker's shadow
        markera.map = mapView_;

    }else {
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
        markera.position = location.coordinate;
        [CATransaction commit];

    }


        GMSCameraUpdate *move = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:location.coordinate zoom:17];
        [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:move];
}
```

I have already set the following parameters of pinfo.list in my project

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription -> Location is required to find out where you are
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription -> Location is required to find out where you are

My testing device  is 8.3 , iphone 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did your `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{` get called?

If not, you need to make sure your `MapViewController` implements the `CLLocationDelegate`. (Ex: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` in your `MapViewController.h` file)

You can try [this working example](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMapsObjcPod) from GitHub, or [the code snippet](https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/a049edb494e0322acf69) from this Gist.

Also, you should test it in your real device, otherwise you have to simulate a location in your XCode simulator (see image below, but it might not always work).

[image]

You have to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your `info.plist` file (note: don't rename or change the extension of the `info.plist` file, the extension has to be `.plist`):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have implemented the CLLocationManagerDelegate , but didUpdateLocations method is never called,



 And status in didChangeAuthorizationStatus always turns 0 ,

Comment: try it in your real device(not simulator), and try [the sample](https://github.com/ziyang0621/GoogleMapsObjcPod) i put in answer.

Comment: ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You should double click to open the `GoogleMapsObjCPod.xcworkspace`, not the `GoogleMapsObjCPod.xcodeproj`

Comment: I know but it still shows the following error. I tried to move you coding into my working part. it still fails

Comment: Have you tried your project in a real device? or turn on the `Location Simulation` in your XCode simulator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81480/discussion-between-raju-gujarati-and-ztan).