# How to get current location using Google maps sdk in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i am using Google SDK for getting route when user walking or driving along the road

But i am not able to get current location and showing in my x code console 0.0 and 0.0(latitude and longitude values) please help me some one for getting current location

### My code is below:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    GMSMapView *_mapView;
    NSMutableArray *_coordinates;
    LRouteController *_routeController;
    GMSPolyline *_polyline;
    GMSMarker *_markerStart;
    GMSMarker *_markerFinish;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    _mapView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)loadView{

    CLLocation *myLocation = _mapView.myLocation;
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    marker.title = @"Current Location";
    marker.map = _mapView;
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:6];
    _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    self.view = _mapView;

    NSLog(@"%f, %f", myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

#pragma mark - GMSMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    _polyline.map = nil;
    _markerStart.map = nil;
    _markerFinish.map = nil;

    [_coordinates addObject:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude]];

    if ([_coordinates count] > 1)
    {
        [_routeController getPolylineWithLocations:_coordinates travelMode:TravelModeDriving andCompletitionBlock:^(GMSPolyline *polyline, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }

            else if (!polyline)
            {
                NSLog(@"No route");
                [_coordinates removeAllObjects];
            }

            else
            {
                _markerStart.position = [[_coordinates objectAtIndex:0] coordinate];
                _markerStart.map = _mapView;

                _markerFinish.position = [[_coordinates lastObject] coordinate];
                _markerFinish.map = _mapView;

                _polyline = polyline;
                _polyline.strokeWidth = 3;
                _polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                _polyline.map = _mapView;
            }
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Please check this stack overflover flow link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317359/google-maps-ios-sdk-how-do-i-get-accurate-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-fr

Comment: please modify my code and post that

Comment: If you want to get the user's current location, you need to use `CLLocationManager`, you can check out [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31034432/4195406) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

getting the location is an asynchronous process. So you need to 'wait' for the location to be updated -- in this case by observing "myLocation"

## observe location

this code only works if _mapView is onscreen

```
// Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
[_mapView addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
            context:NULL];

// Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});
```

## get the location updates:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if (!_firstLocationUpdate) {
    // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
    // location.
    _firstLocationUpdate = YES;
    CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    _mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                     zoom:14];
  }
}
```

Comment: see MyLocationViewController in Google Maps IOS SDK Demos